# Return variable from within object like array

Tags: php

A rather cryptic title, but it's difficult to phrase.

Say I have an object from `mysql_fetch_object()`. I want to use a getter to return a value from a column.

For example, in a class, we have `$this->data`. How can I return say `$this->data->id` (ID column from table) **using an argument from the getter function.**

This won't work, but something along the lines of:

```
public function data($key)
{
    return $this->data[$key];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're searching for are [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

But using `mysql_fetch_assoc` might be better suited for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

what about `return $this->data->$key` ?

or if you implement [ArrayAccess](http://docs.php.net/arrayaccess), return $this->data->$key from the [offsetGet()](http://docs.php.net/arrayaccess.offsetget) function, then you can use $object[$key] to retrieve the data

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your looking for __get method ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php
Not really sure about what you're looking for.

something like.

```
public function __get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now you can access your data as `$obj->key`

Comment: $this->data is an object, if you want to work with it like with an array, you have to cast it to array first. In your case array_key_exists($name, (array) $this->data)